# can we use XMPP smack without google talk servers

Tags: android

Can we use `XMPP` Smack Library to build an chatting app without using Google Talk or Facebook client/server authentication for chat.

Just by authenticating with users phone number with OTP.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi can you pls give me one example

Comment: configure  your own server by openfire and use it for app to app chatting.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480302/using-your-own-xmpp-server-for-android-chat-app-smack-api

Answer (score 0):

Yes Configure Your Own Xmpp Server (Ejabbered Or OpenFire) then connect it to Your App

Use username as Phone Number as whatsapp does and Password as OTP